# Htaccess-rewrite - Exclude some folders in the condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a script that to place watermark on images.

I want a RewriteRule that will exclude the images inside the folders (thumb and thumbprofile). Meaning images inside this folders will not be stamped with watermark

Currently I have this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/thumb|^/profilethumb].*\.(gif|jp?g|png))$ watermark.php?image=$1&watermark=watermark.png [NC]
```

The problem is it does not put watermark on images in (thumb) which is correct but still it stamp watermark in the folder (profilethumb).

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule combined with the condition :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(profile)?thumb(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$ watermark.php?image=$0&watermark=watermark.png [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/(thumb|profilethumb) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !watermark\.php        [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^.]+)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png) [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /watermark.php?image=%1.%2&watermark=watermark.png [NC,L]
```

I guess in `/thumb` and `/profilethumb` there are only images and to exclude both directories from the rule is enough. If there are other files, I don't think  you want them to have the watermark either.

Comment: Only images on that 2 folders

Comment: Okay. The rule-set in my answer should work. I modified it several times because something wasn't right, so decided to exclude only the directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can first skip the two directories `thumb` and `profilethumb` with a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), which doesn't substitute the URL-path, and then process all other images with a second rule

```
RewriteRule ^(?:thumb|profilethumb).*\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ watermark.php?image=$0&watermark=watermark.png [L,NC]
```